# Ford radio unlocking

Tags: ford, audio, ka

I have a Ford Ka and need to re-enter the code. I have removed the radio and have the code (some nice person wrote it on the top of the radio) but I cannot get the "Locked" message off the screen on the radio to enter the code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

There are two types of locks - if you have entered an incorrect code too many times it may be a garage visit (Lock13)

Lock10 is when you have entered an incorrect code 10 times (I think) and can be cleared by holding the "6" button while turning the unit on.

Then you enter the security code the normal way:

Display Shows CODE with " - - - - "

Press Preset Button 1 until the 1st digit is set, then do the same for digits 2, 3 and 4.

Then press Preset Button 5 to Enter

Answer (score 3):

Generally waiting about an hour with will be necessary before the unit will offer you another chance to enter the code. Early **Ford** and Philips radios can make you wait several hours and it's simply a case of leaving the radio on untouched for as long as it takes for the display to change, indicating that it's ready to take the code.

But first be sure that you have the correct code. You can recalculate your code to verify. just see this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KfNMuFFWpw